# How do insert data into pivot table with columns without models?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm learning laravel pivot table and here's what I'm doing. I have a student and subject model with many to many relationship. In my pivot table i have included columns for test1, test2 and test3 so that i can use it to store the student's score for each subject. These are my models

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
    }
}

class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

This is my migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('student_subject', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('student_id');
        $table->integer('subject_id');
        $table->primary(['student_id', 'subject_id']);
        $table->integer('test1')->nullable();
        $table->integer('test2')->nullable();
        $table->integer('test3')->nullable();
    });
}
```

This is where it all got complicated for me. When a student record is created, user is redirected to an enroll page where subjects are selected for the student.

This is my StudController@store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $student = Student::create(request()->all());

    Session::flash('status', "New student's record was added successfully");
    Session::put('firstname', request('firstname'));
    Session::put('lastname', request('lastname'));
    Session::put('student_id', $student->id);
    Session::put('class', $student->class_admitted);

    return redirect('/enroll');
}
```

This is the enroll form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/enroll">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<input type="" name="student_id" value="{{ Session::get('student_id')}}" hidden>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group subjectList">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
            <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="subject_id[]" value="{{ $subject->id }}">  {{ ucwords($subject->name) }}</label></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Enroll
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my EnrollController@store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);

    $student = request('student_id');

    foreach ($request->input('subject_id') as $subject) {
        $student->subjects()->attach($subjects);
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to how I can do insert into the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an array in your `attach()` method, like this:

```
->attach($subjectId, ['test1' => 1, 'test2' => 2]);
```

The `attach()` method will create the entry in the pivot table, the additional attributes will be added.

You can also pass an array of subjects to `attach()`, like this:

```
->attach([1 => ['test1' => 1, 'test2' => 2], 2 => ['test1' => 3, 'test2' => 4]]);
```

And when you need to update the pivot data you can use `sync()`.

As far as I can see now, you do not have anything in your form besides the subject, so I assume you want to update the pivot data later on.

---

Also, you might want to add some additional validation there on both the student and the subjects.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // making sure student exists
    $student = Student::findOrFail(request('student_id'));

    $subjectIds = Subject::whereIn('id', $request->input('subject_id', []))
        ->get()
        ->pluck('id')
        ->all();

    $student->subjects()->attach($subjectIds);

    // you can also use sync here, that way it will add new subjects, keep the ones that already exist (and are posted) and remove subjects not in post
    // $student->subjects()->sync($subjectIds);
}
```

Comment: Working with the second option now as i understand it better than the first but i'm getting an error **Call to a member function get() on array**

Comment: Screaming here, that fixed it. Thanks, I see plucking the each subject id was key here.

Comment: Yeah i forgot a `)` at the end of `whereIn()`. Anyway with this setup, you will only get values of subject_id that actually exist in the database. Just keep in mind that if you are to use sync, it will add and remove your pivots. So when you have subject 1, 2 and 3, and you sync 2, 1 and 3 will be removed.

Comment: Works well for me as the subjects table will always be populated first then a list of the subjects will be displayed for the user to select from. I will use sync when doing an update